# Calculating Text Height as per Apple Documentation

Tags: swift, macos, nslayoutmanager

I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001809-CJBGBIBB) to try and determine the height of a container I would need before placing text in a CATextLayer.  However, I am not getting the expected results.  The returned NSRect is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0).  What am I doing wrong?

```
func heightForStringDrawing(myString: NSString, myFont: NSFont, myWidth: CGFloat) -> NSRect {
    
    let textStorage:NSTextStorage = NSTextStorage.init(string: myString as String)
    let textContainer:NSTextContainer = NSTextContainer.init(containerSize: NSMakeSize(myWidth, CGFloat.infinity))
    let layoutManager:NSLayoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    layoutManager.glyphRange(for: textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    textStorage.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : myFont], range: NSMakeRange(0, textStorage.length))
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0

    return layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
}
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
print(myLayers.heightForStringDrawing(myString: "Some really, really, really, very long text.", myFont: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), myWidth: 66))
```

This results in a returned NSRect as (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), but I expect (0.0, 0.0, 66.0, (a number larger than 0.0 or 14.0)).  It's not even returning the width.

If I send an empty `myString = ""` I get a returned NSRect of (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0).  But still no width, as supplied in the call.

Comment: What about where it says “you must force it to lay out the text, even though you don’t need the glyph range returned by this function.” Seems to me you left out that step.

Comment: @matt I added in the ```layoutManager.glyphRange(for: textContainer)```, but it still isn't working.  I used that boundingRect method, but I want to see if this method is more accurate for precision positioning in a PDF document.

Comment: "I added in the layoutManager.glyphRange(for: textContainer)" But you put it in the wrong place! _Just copy the example you are given!_ Take the code they give you, line by line, in the order they give it to you, and run it. It works perfectly. I got `(0.0, 0.0, 63.1435546875, 102.0)` for your string, which is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that you simply didn't translate the code they gave you into Swift correctly. Translate the *code* they give you *in the order* they give it to you, like this:

```
func heightForStringDrawing(myString:String, myFont:NSFont, myWidth: GFloat) -> NSRect {
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: myString)
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(containerSize: NSMakeSize(myWidth, .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    textStorage.addAttributes([.font : myFont], range: NSMakeRange(0, textStorage.length))
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    layoutManager.glyphRange(for: textContainer) // <- here
    return layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
}
```

Comment: The reason I had the layoutManager.glyphRange up higher in the code was because in the document they showed they had it set to autorelease, which since I do not know Objective-C I had assumed the call needed to be up higher.  My bad.  Thank you!